# Use `self` in drivers to return a custom properties,

Tags: drivers, custom-attributes

I'm trying to access in a driver the custom property of an object using `self` as I don't need to specify manually the object everytime. However, I can't find the appropriate syntax, I always get errors:

[image]

Comment: aah...just realized your are "in" geometry nodes. ...nope that doesn't work

Comment: this works in "normal" fields of the object - like x, y, scale etc.

Comment: but what works is this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVp6i.png

Comment: @Chris Argh, too bad (I also tried in Materials, it also fails). I'm aware of your proposed solution, but it requires me to pin the object. So it's a bit annoying to use, for instance it complicates how I can reuse my geometry nodes (I need to make it an input of the geometry node, and add everytime the driver from the modifier tab)... There is no more efficient solution I guess?

Comment: It's because self is node tree or node itself, not the object.

Comment: @Crantisz Hum I see. And from this node tree, can't I access somehow to the input of the node tree?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't get to parent data through children then it can be a multiuser data

Comment: I just made a rightclickselect proposal that, if implemented, would solve this issue. Upvote it!
https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Wqjx/?sorting=hot

Comment: @ChameleonScales Thanks!